# display a boolean as a yes/no radio group

Tags: grails

I have a domain class which has a few Boolean properties. The scaffolding feature builds a view which used checkboxes for these properties, but I would really like for these properties to be represented with two radio buttons (Yes/No). What would be the most appropriate way of doing this (a custom tag maybe)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up using the following radio group:

```
<g:radioGroup name="amountPayableVariation" labels="['Yes','No']" values="['true','false']" value="${contractInstance?.amountPayableVariation}">
<span>${it.radio} ${it.label}</span>
</g:radioGroup>
```

Comment: If you are consistent using 'Yes' and 'No' for labels and 'true' and 'false' for values, you could reduce this down to a custom tag that only needs a name parameter and a bean parameter.

Answer (score 3):

Install the templates for the scaffolds:

```
grails install-templates
```

Then you have can change the templates, which are rendered for each type. Check the file `renderEditor.template` in your `src/templates/scaffolding` folder. You have to change the `renderBooleanEditor` appropriate.