# Grails Radio Buttons arrangement

Tags: javascript, jquery, grails, gsp

Hi I am making four radio buttons which are dependent on each other.

The buttons are First, second, A, B

```
First    Second
A         B
```

the buttons are like if we select **First** then only **First** is select and the buttons **A** and **B** becomes disable.  if we select **Second** then both **A** and **B** becomes enable and we can select one button from them.

```
<g:radioGroup name="RadioGrails"
              labels="['First','Second']"
              values="[1,2]">
<label>
        <span class="radioSpan">${it.radio}</span>
        ${it.label}
</label>
</g:radioGroup>
```

The radio buttons for A and B

```
<g:radioGroup name="ABRadioButtons"
                  labels="['A','B']"
                  values="[1,2]">
    <label>
            <span class="radioSpan">${it.radio}</span>
            ${it.label}
    </label>
    </g:radioGroup>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use :

(of course, you have to set the initial state of the second radioGroup...)

```
<g:radioGroup class="radiograils" name="RadioGrails" labels="['First','Second']" values="[1,2]">
    <label>
        <span class="radioSpan">
            ${it.radio}
        </span> ${it.label}
    </label>
</g:radioGroup>

<g:radioGroup class="abradiobuttons" name="ABRadioButtons" labels="['A','B']" values="[1,2]">
    <label>
        <span class="radioSpan">
            ${it.radio}
        </span> ${it.label}
    </label>
</g:radioGroup>

<script src="${request.contextPath}/js/jquery-2.0.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.radiograils').change(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == 2) {
            $('.abradiobuttons').prop('disabled', false);
        } else {
            $('.abradiobuttons').prop('checked', false);
            $('.abradiobuttons').prop('disabled', true);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. when I select First it disables A and B , then if i select Second then it enables A and B then further if i select A (with second), then if i switch back to First it will disable A and B , but the A which is selected earlier is selected in disable mode.in this  i want no selection  in A and B when i select First again .. is it possible .

Comment: of course! :-) I modified the answer above with a checked->false entry. Hope it helps.

Comment: Awesome ...it's working thanks alot :) .. could you please upvote the question

Comment: How do i set the boolean value for the both Radio buttons for one field-isState of the domain class as (True for First) and Falsefor second like                                                                                              values ="['${DomainClass?.isState}','${DomainClass?.isState}']"

Comment: as described [here](http://docs.grails.org/2.0.3/ref/Tags/radioGroup.html) you should use the **value** attribute like `<g:radioGroup class="abradiobuttons" name="ABRadioButtons" labels="['A','B']" values="[1,2]" value="${domainClassInstance?.state}">`

Comment: what if i need to save value as false when we select the radio button like value="${domainClassInstance?.isState}.False"  this is just to explain .. i don't know how exactly it works

Comment: Ah, I see... you would like to have 1+2 converted to true/false? 1 is true and 2 is false?

Comment: I would use `value="${domainClassInstance.isState() ? 1 : 2}"`

Comment: Or you could use directly a boolean expression for the radio-group like [described in this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8193324/display-a-boolean-as-a-yes-no-radio-group)